# Javascript loop vs C loop for complex array

Tags: javascript, c, node.js

I am running some complex loop in node.js. But there is a problem I am facing. The time it takes for the loop to complete is around 200-300 ms which is very high. Will it be efficient if I convert also this piece of code to `C`? Or is there a better way? I have tried using `clustering`, `fork()`, `reverse loops` but nothing seems to make much difference

Some sample data

`containers //Multidimensional 2D array on each index has array of 8 elements` something like `[ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] ... ]`

`deleteItems= [1,2,3]`

```
        for (let indexi = 0; indexi < containers.length; indexi++) {
            var shuoldRemove    = false;
            for (let indexj = 0; indexj < containers[indexi].length; indexj++)
            {
                for (let indexOfIPCPR = 0; indexOfIPCPR < deleteItems.length; indexOfIPCPR++){
                    if (containers[indexi][indexj] == deleteItems[indexOfIPCPR]){
                        shouldRemove = true;
                        shouldRemove && indexOfNextRound.splice(indexOfNextRound.indexOf(indexi),1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The above code is further inside another loop. Which is much more worse.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags. Also, I don't think this is an answerable question. I wouldn't expect a good js engine to have problems with executing loops quickly, so it's what's *inside* the loop that takes time. If you think it helps, try to come up with a C implementation, I doubt anybody can predict it will be better (or, maybe even worse).

Comment: Maybe filtering inner arrays would be faster? Can you replace inner arrays reference with copy of it?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't loop over `indexOfNextRound` instead of having the 2 outermost loops, since that is the array you're actually affecting.

Comment: You might want to consider leaving loops early if all items have been found and removed (in your example "breaking" after having removed all 3 `deleteItems` saves looping over the remaining 5 entries for each array)

Answer (score 1):

I think for very complex arrays you can get better speed by caching the array length. I see that you are getting the length in every iteration. This is how the loop should be updated to reduce the time taken in calculating array lengths. Please remember that modern JS engines do such optimization on their own. So, this may change nothing.

```
for (let indexi = 0, maxi = containers.length; indexi < maxi; indexi++) {
            var shuoldRemove    = false;
            for (let indexj = 0, maxj = containers[indexi].length; indexj < maxj; indexj++)
            {
                for (let indexOfIPCPR = 0, maxDelete = deleteItems.length; indexOfIPCPR < maxDelete; indexOfIPCPR++){
                    if (containers[indexi][indexj] == deleteItems[indexOfIPCPR]){
                        shouldRemove = true;
                        shouldRemove && indexOfNextRound.splice(indexOfNextRound.indexOf(indexi),1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this is not that simple and mainly depends on the content of your loop. But few relevant points that maybe will help you do decide:

The event-loop of Node.js is single threaded. It doesn't mean that everything will run in one thread - I/O (network operations, writing to files, etc) operations have their own threads and they will run async. BUT, if your code doesn't have lots of I/O, it will pretty much run in a single thread.

In C, you can create threads as you wish and run your code concurrently. But it will be more efficient only if your code **can** run concurrently, without the possibly high overhead of communicating between the threads, syncing them. So, **if** you can split the resources and the input data to few independent groups and then pass each group to a thread and run them all concurrently, that will probably will be more efficient then run it all in a single thread.

These will be the main differences between running it in Node.js and C - **threads-wise**. Of course, there are more aspects that differ between Node.js and C.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But the main algorithm was written in MATLab. It was running fast. So I thought of moving the code to C